# How to sync RDS database across regions in AWS

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-datasync

I have two MYSQL RDS Instance in Ohio and Mumbai region. Both RDS instance should sync each other. Does AWS have any services to enable sync between RDS Database? else should we configure to achieve? Both RDS should sync by hourly or daily. Can any one please advice on this?

Comment: I had a look at AWS Mysql RDS instance read-replica. I thought this would be helpful for my case. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, RDS read replica can be setup in another region, but only for reading purposes ideally.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot setup bi-directional replication with 2 RDS instances. However, you can provision an RDS instance in one region as writer, and create a read replica for it in another region. It can be used only for reading purposes. You can make it writable, but it would not sync data back to first region, and can also cause replication issues.

Even a somewhat manual method to sync data can cause data consistency issues.